# Unable To Add Package To Buidroot

Tags: linux, embedded, buildroot

I'm trying to add a package to buildroot, but I'm not having much success. The package I'm trying to add is an `autotools` package called `scew`. I've followed the buildroot guidelines about adding packages, and although the package is listed when `make menuconfig` is run, when I run make the package is missing from the final `rootfs.tar`.

I've also copied over another simple `.mk` file that's used to install `which`, and changed the variable names and URL accordingly. Here is my copy of `scew.mk`:

```
SCEW_VERSION = 1.1.3
SCEW_SITE = http://savannah.nongnu.org/download/scew/
SCEW_LICENSE = GPLv3
SCEW_LICENSE_FILES = COPYING

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

In the same directory I have `Config.in`, which looks like:

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_SCEW
 bool "scew"
 help
     google scew
```

I've also added the following lines to `package/Config.in`:

```
menu "My Packages"

  menu "Packages I Wrote"
   source "package/MyPackages/packagesIWrote/hello/Config.in"
   source "package/MyPackages/packagesIWrote/helloworld/Config.in"
  endmenu

  menu "External Packages"
   source "package/MyPackages/external-packages/scew/Config.in"
  endmenu

endmenu
```

This part seems to work, as the packages are listed and can be selected. The hello and helloworld packages are copies from a guide to adding packages, taken from this website (written in french):[Adding Hello World](http://www.linuxembedded.fr/2011/03/ajouter-un-package-dans-buildroot-en-5-minutes/).

The hello world packages also do not work. I'd be glad of any advice at all, as it seems I'm just going around in circles on this one, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you modify the .config file to enable this package?

Comment: What happens if you run make scew-build?  You could also check a makefile debugger like remake to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

To construct the appropriate file:

1. diff your source package from the original into a file called. packagename-number-description.patch. where. packagename - has to be identical to the package name. ...
2. Place this file into the package at the same level as the [packagename]. mk file and the package/Config.in file.